# Center bootstrap background button?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have an issue the `+` sign of the bootstrap button which isn't centered like in this image :

[image: centered].

I tried to wrap the `button` with a `div` with `justify-content-center align-content-center text-center` classes.

```css
.btn-plus {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/30) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center text-center m-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-plus"></button>
</div>
```

I tried also adding `background-position: center;` to the `btn-plus` in the inspector but neither of what i tried is solving the problem.

How can i fix the problem?

Comment: I've added the Bootstrap library to your demo. Please revise further so we see what you see. Also, where did you get the idea to add an icon class like that? That's not an approach I'm familiar with. Generally, icons are on elements _inside_ the button.

Comment: @isherwood i add the code for the `btn-plus` class.

Comment: Please revise the _existing_ snippet so it shows your problem. It's not clear what's going on.

Comment: You can upload your plus image to the post and use that URL in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try what you did but in the class of your button

```
.divButton {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

and set this class to your div.
The classes what you provided are css properties.